# Extracting non-duplicate features between layers in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, arcgis-10.4

Just making an example: Layer B has 5 points. There's a layer(A) contains 10 points and 5 of which  duplicate(totoally same and overlap) with layer B.

How to output the other 5 non-duplicate points in layer A as a new feature?

Or just delete the 5 duplicate points from it?

I don't think `CLIP` tool can solve this.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: First, spatial select from A where its features intersect those in B, then "Switch Selection." Then, export features (or create new layer from selection).

Comment: How to spatial select?Is it a function set in table options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Select by Location* where **Feature A** is your *Input Feature Layer*
2. Set the *Relationship* to "Intersect" or "Are Identical to"
3. Set the *Selecting Feature* to **Feature B**; run the query
4. Delete the selected points from **Feature A's** attribute table